# Filter Between on multiple columns Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Hi I am trying to filter based on criteria on two columns. I am trying to use the advanced filter option but it is not working logically the way I want it to. I think I may have to write an input box and find a way to do it with vba, but I want to make sure I am not missing anything before investing time in that route.

Here is a sample of what i am trying to do

```
   A     B
1  20   30
2  21   35
3  7    15
4  26   27
5  5    15
6  9    12 
7  24   26


output

   A    B
1  20   30
2  21   35 
4  26   27
7  24   26
```

in this example I would want to show only rows that have the 26 in between a and b. Not sure If i can combine columns and filter that?

Comment: Use the macro recorder and do it manually, and it will create code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a column header, then you can use the AutoFilter (either from the Data tab, or via VBA)

For VBA, define your range, then use the AutoFilter method to add filters on each column.  You appear to be looking for rows where **Column A** <= 26 <= **Column B**:

```
Columns("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=26" 'Column A, less than or equal to 26
Columns("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=26" 'Column B, greater than or equal to 26
```

And here is a more generic form:

```
Sub FilterColumnsForNumber(rTMP As Range, dNumber As Double)
    If rTMP.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode Then rTMP.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode 'Remove autofilter in case it is somewhere else in the worksheet
    rTMP.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & CStr(dNumber) 'First column of Range, less than or equal to dNumber
    rTMP.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & CStr(dNumber) 'Second column of Range, greater than or equal to dNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use AutoFilter with a helper column.  In **C2** enter:

```
=AND(MIN(A2:B2)<=26,MAX(A2:B2)>=26)
```

and copy down:

[image]

and with the filter applied:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested if like

```
=IF(B1<26, IF(C1>26, TRUE,FALSE), FALSE)
```

and then filter the cell which the formula cell is `true`